# Variable with multiple values in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a variable with multiple values, and use it in a command that will execute these values one by one.

Example:

```
value=(a, b, c, d, e)
```

By using `echo "$value"` I would like these values to be passed on to echo one by one.

When I use `ARRAY=(a, b, c, d, e)`, they all get executed at once. Which I'm trying to avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Then loop through the array with a `for`. By the way, no comma between the values. (Or those values actually contain the commas too?)

Answer (score 14):

```
# declare the array
ARRAY=( a "b c" d e )

# to get the elements out of the array, use this syntax:
#   "${ARRAY[@]}" -- with the quotes

for element in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    echo "$element"
done
```

```
a
b c
d
e
```

Comment: Works great, thx.